# How to I make it so the div shows when the menu button is hovered over without altering the position: absolute part?

Tags: html, css

I want to show .navdrop when hovering over .but. Here is my css:

```
.but {
 background-color: blue;
 padding: 5px;
 float: left;
}

.but a:hover {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.but a:hover .navdrop {
display: block !important;
}

 .navdrop {
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
right: auto;
top: 21.5rem;
display: none;
}

.navdrop ul {
list-style-type: none;
background-color: skyblue;
padding: 10px;
}

.navdrop li {
 padding: 2px 10px 2px 2px;
 background-color: blue;
}

li .navlinkd {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

.navlinkd:hover {
 box-shadow: 8px 5px 4px rgba(124, 112, 79, 0.7);
 background-color: skyblue;
}

.navlinkd:active {
 box-shadow: none;
 background-color: #3c94d1;

@media screen and (min-width: 1030px) {
 span {
display: none;
 }
}
```

I don't want .but to link anywhere but I'm new to this and none of the solutions available worked for me. Here is my HTML for reference. I am wondering if it i something to do with the fact that the display: none can't be reversed, in which case, how do I make it show?

```
<div class="liststyle">
  <ul>
    <li class="but"><a href>Menu &#8595;</a></li>
      <div class="navdrop">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="Intro.html">Intro</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="a.html">a</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="b.html">b</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="c.html">c</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="d.html">d</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="e.html">e</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="f.html">f</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="g.html">g</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="h.html">h</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  <ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a few side-notes:

- You have a closing `<ul>` instead of `</ul>`.
- Media queries can't be inside selectors; you appear to have missed the closing bracket in your `.navlinkd:active`.

I've corrected both of these points in my example.

Second, there is **[no concept of a parent selector](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)** in CSS, meaning you cannot change the display of `.navdrop` by targeting the `<a>` child of `.but`. **However**, you **can** achieve what you're looking by targeting the hover of `.but` itself, and making use of the **[adjacent sibling selector (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)**:

```
.but:hover + .navdrop {
  display: block;
}
```

Note that I've removed the `!important` from the above, as it's not necessary, and `!important` has the highest level of **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** (meaning it should only ever be used as a last resort).

Also, toggling a menu's visibility on hover is essentially pointless without JavaScript, as you'll never be able to actually click on any of the links.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.but {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.but a:hover {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.but:hover ~ .navdrop {
  display: block;
}

.navdrop {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  /*top: 21.5rem;*/
  top: 3.5rem;
  display: none;
}

.navdrop ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: skyblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navdrop li {
  padding: 2px 10px 2px 2px;
  background-color: blue;
}

li .navlinkd {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navlinkd:hover {
  box-shadow: 8px 5px 4px rgba(124, 112, 79, 0.7);
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.navlinkd:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #3c94d1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1030px) {
  span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="liststyle">
  <ul>
    <li class="but"><a href>Menu &#8595;</a></li>
    <div class="navdrop">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="navlinkd" href="Intro.html">Intro</a></li>
        <li><a class="navlinkd" href="a.html">a</a></li>
        <li><a class="navlinkd" href="b.html">b</a></li>
        <li><a class="navlinkd" href="c.html">c</a></li>
        <li><a class="navlinkd" href="d.html">d</a></li>
        <li><a class="navlinkd" href="e.html">e</a></li>
        <li><a class="navlinkd" href="f.html">f</a></li>
        <li><a class="navlinkd" href="g.html">g</a></li>
        <li><a class="navlinkd" href="h.html">h</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that I've modified the `top` in `.navdrop` for this example so that the menu will be shown without any scrolling.

Considering the links cannot be clicked on, what you may want is to use JavaScript to open the relevant menu on hover, and **delay** its closure. Unfortunately, that **cannot** be done with CSS.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: That sorted it, I'm really new and that took two days. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it using javascript. I assigned some `id`s to your HTML elements so that it is easy to implement (Can do that using the class name as well). also I changed the `top` value of `.navdrop` class, otherwise it appears far from the '**Menu**'. According to this javascript, menu dropdown appears when you hover on **Menu** link and disappears when the mouse leaves the area covered by outermost `div`.

```js
var menuDiv = document.getElementById('menu-div');
var menuHeader = document.getElementById('but');
var menuDropdown = document.getElementById('nav-drop');

menuHeader.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
  menuDropdown.style.display = 'block';
});
menuDiv.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
  menuDropdown.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
.but {
 background-color: blue;
 padding: 5px;
 float: left;
}

.but a:hover {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.but a:hover .navdrop {
display: block !important;
}

 .navdrop {
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
right: auto;
top: 2.5rem;
display: none;
}

.navdrop ul {
list-style-type: none;
background-color: skyblue;
padding: 10px;
}

.navdrop li {
 padding: 2px 10px 2px 2px;
 background-color: blue;
}

li .navlinkd {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

.navlinkd:hover {
 box-shadow: 8px 5px 4px rgba(124, 112, 79, 0.7);
 background-color: skyblue;
}

.navlinkd:active {
 box-shadow: none;
 background-color: #3c94d1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1030px) {
 span {
display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="liststyle" id="menu-div">
  <ul>
    <li class="but" id="but"><a href>Menu &#8595;</a></li>
      <div class="navdrop" id="nav-drop">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="Intro.html">Intro</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="a.html">a</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="b.html">b</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="c.html">c</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="d.html">d</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="e.html">e</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="f.html">f</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="g.html">g</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlinkd" href="h.html">h</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```